# lost wallet PLEASE HELP

Tags: blockchain

Back when the article came out about the Silk Road.  I followed the instructions in the article to get into the Silk Road.  I just wanted to see it. I was prompted to buy bitcoin so I purchased a small amount.  I don't do drugs and felt guilty about it being on my desktop so I put it in the trash.  I have a Mac.  6 years later someone emptied my trash.  I wrote down the username and password.  Can anybody help me find my old wallet?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by username and password? Was it the Silk Road username and password? Wallets that are stored locally on your computer are stored with a public key and a private key.

If the username and password that you have is for Silk Road, then your money is not recoverable. This is because they own your private keys on their site and now that they have been shutdown, you won't be able to interact with your wallet.

If you have a username and password not from Silk Road, it is more likely that you had an online wallet which means that it might still be recoverable.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know your account's private key or the seed that some wallets provide to recover it. Otherwise, unless you have a backup copy of your wallet.dat file, the amount of bitcoins in that account is lost forever. If you deleted only the wallet app and not its files you could try to see if you still have the wallet.dat file in memory, re-download the wallet and importing such file. It should be protected by a password that you have given